# Live boot or installed Linux USB to clean windows

Tags: usb, live-usb

I am planning on making a Ubuntu USB to clean up Windows based computers. So my question is, should I just create a live boot USB to clean Windows based computers? Could I install Ubuntu on a USB to do this or would it not work, or put my USB at risk (I know generally virus/malware doesn't effect Linux)?

And if I should just stick to a live boot USB, would having a persistent partition be a risk or no?

Comment: A Full install to USB is a little more stable than a Persistent install however it can't be used to install Ubuntu like a Live or Persistent install can.

Comment: Is not clear what you are asking. A typical startup USB pendrive with Ubuntu let you both install from it and use it as a live distro. Also (if you configure it while creation) you'll have persistent space on USB drive. You can just use that pendrive to overwrite completely your Windows partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method to clean Windows machines in the past and I haven't had any issues.

You could try using a tool like ClamAV to check for malware and remove it.
You can download the software here https://www.clamav.net/downloads/production/clamav-0.101.2.tar.gz

Just be sure not to automatically blow away everything that is decected by clamAV because it could be detecting "false positives"